# [LLVM][RISCV] Easy way to promote byte loads/stores to word/dword loads/stores?

Tags: clang, llvm, riscv, riscv32

I'm trying to hack the Clang/LLVM compiler to do work around a specific RISC-V hardware issue on the processor I am working on.

It appears that loading addresses that are not 16/32-bit aligned does not work as expected. To work around this, I'd like to modify the compiler to change all `lb/lbu` and `sb` instructions to instead work on a full word or dword.

For example, I have the following struct:

```
union Flags
{
  struct
  {
    uint32_t enabled   :  1;
    uint32_t reserved  :  7;
    uint32_t foo       :  1;
    uint32_t reserved2 : 23; 
  };
  uint32_t u32All;
};
```

Right now, when the compiled program tries to access a pointer containing `Flags->foo`, it does so with an `lbu` instruction that is at address X+1(byte). This offset is truncated by the hardware and so it reads the address X instead, which would return the `enabled` flag instead of the `foo` flag.
I need to promote the load into a word/dword and then operate on it properly.

I'm not knowledgeable about LLVM in the slightest. I've tried poking around RISCVISelLowering.cpp, but the only thing I've managed to do is cause `lld` to crash when it attempts to legalize the load ops.

Looking for any help or guidance you might be able to provide. Thank you!

Comment: How does that proposal work around alignment issues?  Can you give an example?

Comment: @ErikEidt, I updated the description with a better example.

Comment: You mean like this: https://godbolt.org/z/dqGYrPvWG ?  If something other, can you do a godbolt example.

Comment: @ErikEidt, I think this is more in line with the codebase I am working in. https://godbolt.org/z/bK684Toxq

Comment: Ok, so naively, we would expect `enabled`&`reserved` to occupy a byte at 12(a0), and that makes 13(a0) looks like the right offset for `foo`, so what's the offset / alignment issue involved?

Comment: The hardware itself, upon receiving a non-word aligned address, will truncate it. So an address of 0x100 is fine, but an address of 0x10d is not. It will truncate the address to 0x10c before performing the load, which provides the wrong data returned.

Comment: That's not how RISC V is defined: it is byte addressable.  So, what custom/modified hardware does that?

Comment: I understand it is byte addressable. Unfortunately there is a hardware bug, which is why I am looking for a software workaround.

Comment: There is no obvious foolproof way for compile-time software to be confident that the address it will use is odd since that 13(a0) is an offset from whatever is in a0!  Sure it could guess that from 13 alone being odd, though if you're packing the data tightly as you are, base pointers themselves might be odd, throwing off the guess that 13(a0) is odd by the value 13 alone being odd.  However, perhaps someone will be able to suggest some software approach.